# Obj C - What is the most efficient way to access NSArray members stored in one custom class from another unrelated custom class?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiview

I am coding my first iOS game and after refactoring my code and moving methods around to align with basic MVC principles I realize that I now need to have access to a static NSArray of UIColors from multiple instances of a UIView subclass.  My game generates many blocks of colors (appearance wise resembles Tetris) and is a grid of UIView subclasses.  Each block has a property with a int value which along with "objectAtIndex" determines which UIColor in the array to use as the view fill color.

I realize if I put the static array of UIColors inside the view subclass, this will be very inefficient and each instance will repeat the storing of the array.  I would like to put it in another class which handles many other game play setup and logistics - basically the brain of the game of which there is only one instance (I believe this is called a singleton).

So I am asking for help on how to best access the array if I create it as a property in this singleton.  Keep in mind that because I will be creating hundreds of instances of UIView subclasses that will be accessing these UIColor values, access efficiency is key.  Would also be interested in hearing any alternative approaches, and pros/cons of each.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: If you are creating hundreds of `UIView`s, then I doubt array access would be a tighter bottleneck than all the memory allocation and initialization and gfx a view does...

Comment: The same way you'd access anything between classes.  The fact that it's an NSArray is irrelevant to how you reference it.  And if the same array is accessed from multiple classes (or multiple instances of the same class) that does not mean that the array is copied (unless you go out of your way to do it wrong).  Only the reference to the array needs to be passed around.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you need no more than a property for your view's `UIColor`. If you want to avoid duplicate instances, your controller may hold the array of colors and set the color at creation. The storage required in that case is just one pointer (and you could remove that `int`). Even referencing the array would require a pointer.

Note that these objects (`UIColor`, `NSArray`) use reference counting and are immutable. So you just have to make sure you use references to a unique set of colors to avoid duplication.

Really, you should avoid creating 100s of `UIView`s. `UIView` graphs just don't scale very high. Rather than focus on duplicate colors, focus on how you could draw the game without all those `UIView`s (although it could be much more complex, depending on what you need to draw).

Comment: Interested to hear what other options beside using UIViews for the blocks of color displayed on screen you had in mind?  Thanks for the information you already provided.  Very helpful.

Comment: @KangleC Filling rects within your view is an easy starting point. It's an introductory subject to implementing `-drawRect:`, and there are multiple tutorials online which demonstrate using an API like `CGContextFillRect`. Once your `-drawRect:` can fill a rect, then try drawing a checkerboard in `-drawRect:` (using one `UIView` instance), then consider how your game could be drawn/represented using `CGContext*` (Quartz drawing) functions within `drawRect:`.

Comment: Thanks Justin!  I was incorrectly using drawRect to fill each newly created subView fully with a single shaded rect when I should have drawn multiple shaded rects in the one main view, bypassing the new for so many subViews.  Great tip, and silly oversight on my part!  Like I said, this is my first real App.

Answer (score 0):

If it's the same `UIView` subclass that will be accessing this array, then have it be a static variable in that class's implementation file.

Comment: Thanks for your quick response.  Is it really that simple?

Comment: You need to create a static variable to hold the array. You'll probably need to have a method that will initialize it on first access, but after that point it can just use the same array that you've already initialized.

Comment: @KangleC: Well, it's not really an MVC design, but you can certainly assign an array to a static variable.